# Select month only from Datetime in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, select, group-by

I have a trouble in selecting month part only from the `datetime`. I have a column named **payment_date** in table transaction. I want to `select * from transaction` and `group by` month of **payment_date**. I have try with this code :

```
$selectedYearTrx = $connectDB->table('transaction')                                  
    ->join('payment_channel','transaction.payment_channel_id','=','payment_channel.id') 
    ->select('id','payment_date', 'payment_channel_id','amount',DB::raw('MONTH(payment_date) as monthPayment'))
    ->whereYear('payment_date', '=', $year)
    ->where('status','=','S')
    ->wherein('payment_channel_id', [1,2,3])
    ->where('currency','=','IDR')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('payment_channel_id','id','monthPayment');
```

But, I'm getting error in `monthPayment` in group by. The error is call a member function *groupby()*.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should put ->get() at the end of the code )

```
$selectedYearTrx = $connectDB->table('transaction')
                             ->join('payment_channel','transaction.payment_channel_id','=','payment_channel.id') 
                             ->select('id','payment_date', 'payment_channel_id','amount',DB::raw('MONTH(payment_date) as monthPayment'))
                             ->whereYear('payment_date', '=', $year)
                             ->where('status','=','S')
                             ->wherein('payment_channel_id', [1,2,3])
                             ->where('currency','=','IDR')
                             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                             ->get()
                             ->groupBy('payment_channel_id','id','monthPayment');
```

should be

```
$selectedYearTrx = $connectDB->table('transaction')                                 
                             ->join('payment_channel','transaction.payment_channel_id','=','payment_channel.id') 
                             ->select('id','payment_date', 'payment_channel_id','amount',DB::raw('MONTH(payment_date) as monthPayment'))
                             ->whereYear('payment_date', '=', $year)
                             ->where('status','=','S')
                             ->wherein('payment_channel_id', [1,2,3])
                             ->where('currency','=','IDR')
                             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                             ->groupBy('payment_channel_id','id','monthPayment')->get();
```

Comment: Oh my bad, thanks for that @Nour , But, i get new error in `DB::raw('MONTH(payment_date) as monthPayment')`. I got the error like this : `function month (timestamp without timezone) does not exist`. Can you help me to deal with this error?